# Manual proxy configuration

Tags: 11.10, proxy, documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure proxy authentication?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65828/how-can-i-configure-proxy-authentication)

How can I set the user and password, GUI mode not terminal, for my proxy in Oneiric Ocelot?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy settings should be in Network settings. 
Like System->Preferences->Network Proxy

Here is a similar question.

[How do system wide proxy settings work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61627/how-do-system-wide-proxy-settings-work)