# Bash Script to set "system wide" proxy settings

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, proxy

I am wondering if there is a command (or series of commands) that would do the same thing as network-network proxy-apply system wide.
I believe I can export a variable, but I think that that button does more then that (according to this: [How do system wide proxy settings work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61627/how-do-system-wide-proxy-settings-work)).

I am wondering if there is a way to fire off the exact thing that this button does from the command line.

I am using a socks proxy with ssh, and I am trying to create a bash script that will allow me to proxy system wide, without opening up any GUIs.